# Large title automatically expands when collapsed and button changes title. Any thoughts?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, preferslargetitles

I have a view with a large title navigation bar, and a scrollview with a content view inside it. The scrollview is scrolling normally (alwaysBouncesVertical set to true) and the large title collapses and expands as it is supposed to.

I have a button at the bottom of the screen, and when I click it, I change its title. The weird thing is, that when I change it, if the navigation bar is collapsed, it will immediately expand and make the scrollview scroll a bit up, making the button go almost totally out of the screen. From this point on, scrolling works normally again and I can scroll back to the button without any problems.

Do you guys know why setting the title with the regular

`self.button.setTitle("", for: .normal)`

Would trigger the navigation bar expansion?

I tried setting the text to many different strings. I also tried doing other changes to the button layout (such as disabling it) but none of these changes produced the same problem.

Comment: The button at the bottom, is it inside the contentView which is inside the scrollView? Or is it outside the scrollView in a fixed position?

Comment: Exactly your first question, the button is at the bottom, pinned to the bottom of the contentView. 
Scrollview is pinned to the safe area anchors, content view has its left and right anchors pinned to the UIViewController's root view, and its top and bottom anchors pinned to the scroll view. 
The content view is composed of three UILabels, a stack view (which contains a group of components, each component is composed of two UILabels and a fixed height view). Button's height is constrained to a fixed value.